# PHP MYSQL VALUE variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops, string-concatenation

I would like to save for value from the database in a `string` . I learn PHP and still just do not understand this grade

```
$db_user = $database->runSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM users");
while($feld = mysql_fetch_array($db_user)){ 
   $save= $feld['username'].",";     
}
// Tom,Anne,Alf
echo $save;
```

Unfortunately, it saves me a value here: `tom,`

Comment: because it shows you the last value always. Find it out how loop works.

Comment: You are re-assigning `$save` for each iteration of the while-loop and only printing after the last iteration. That's why it's only printing 'Tom'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$save = '';
$db_user = $database->runSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM users");
while($feld = mysql_fetch_array($db_user)) 
{ 
   $save .= $feld['username'].","; 

}
// Tom,Anne,Alf
echo $save;
```

The `$save` variable is now adding the result from the database onto the string, this is called  concatenation. You can read more about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

Comment: realy?? yet so simple -.- Thank you : D

Comment: No problem! If this solved your question please check it as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The WHILE-Loop overwrites your `$save` every time. If you want to concatenate it with the previous values, use `$save .= $feld['username'].",";`  (mind the extra `.` )

However, this will yield Tom,Anne,Alf, in the end, so you should remove the last "," to obtain the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

Without the trailing comma as your comment suggests.

```
$save = "";
$concat = "";
$db_user = $database->runSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM users");
while($feld = mysql_fetch_array($db_user)) 
{ 
   $save .= $concat . $feld['username'];
   $concat = ",";
}

// Tom,Anne,Alf
echo $save;
```

Answer (score 0):

The trailing comma can be handled without introducing another variable. This is how I usually do it:

```
    $save = "";
    $db_user = $database -> runSQLQuery('SELECT username FROM users', MYSQL_ASSOC);
    while ( $feld = mysql_fetch_array($db_user)) {
        if ( $save != "" ) $save .= ',';
        $save .= $feld['username'];
    }
```

I've changed your SELECT to make it clear you are only interested in username. It is also faster.

It's also faster and cleaner to specify MYSQL_ASSOC (instead of the default MYSQL_BOTH) so you don't get two copies of all the fields.

Stylistically, I always use single quotes in PHP for simple strings so PHP doesn't need to check for variable substitution etc.  With one exception: I use `""` for the empty string because `''` is easy to confuse with `"`.